# ALSA passthrough latency

Tags: latency, alsa

I am working on an embedded Linux application with audio passthrough using ALSA. It has very stringent latency requirements.

The output buffer is as small as possible which results in an occasional (perhaps once an hour) underrun on the output. This is acceptable. However, when it occurs, it causes a "backup" in the capture buffer and the result is a creeping increase in latency.

There doesn't seem to be a reliable way to know how much output data was lost in order to discard the same amount of input. I can experiment, but even though it's an embedded application it needs to be device independent, so we need a reliable solution.

Does anyone know a way to determine how much data was lost, or if it is always one buffer, or have other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want the PCM devices to stop on an underrun/overrun, configure them not to stop by setting the stop threshold to the boundary value. Then they will just continue to run, and the number of available frames will continue to increase (for capture) or decrease (for playback). (Not all of those frames will be usable; the ring buffer just wraps around.)